# ADAL 3.13 - Graph API

Tags: api, powershell, adal, microsoft-graph-api

My problem is for the "SCOPE or PERMISSION" in ADAL for GRAPH API.

I'm using ADAL 3.13 and I've created the following script:

```
$adal = "C:\Users\filippog\Desktop\ADAL\_Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
$adalforms = "C:\Users\filippog\Desktop\ADAL\_Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.Platform.dll"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adal)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($adalforms)

[string] $adTenant = "****"
[string] $clientId = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2" #id client of powershell
[string] $resourceAppIdURI = "https://graph.windows.net/"
[string] $authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$adTenant"
[uri] $redirectUri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" #redirect urPowerShell - i of powershell
[string] $resourceURI = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/'
[string] $scope = "scope=mail.read"

$authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority #,$false

$PromptBehavior = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]::Always
$platformParam = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters" -ArgumentList $PromptBehavior
$userId = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier" -ArgumentList "****", "OptionalDisplayableId"

$authResult = $authContext.AcquireTokenAsync($resourceUri, $clientId, $redirectUri, $platformParam, $userId, $scope)
$AuthHeader=$authResult.result.CreateAuthorizationHeader()

$headers = @{
  "Authorization" = $AuthHeader
  "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $headers -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages -Method Get
```

My problem is that when I execute a script and invoke a graph (for example, `graph/v1.0/me` it works, but when I invoke `graph/v1.0/me/messages`, the script returns `error 403`.

Comment: You really shouldn't use the client ID of applications that are not your own. It's really easy to register your own native client application, and you'll get additional advantages (e.g. you can control the naming and the branding in the sign-in prompts).

Comment: The PowerShell Client ID does not have the scope for mail messages.

Answer (score 1):

Per Philippe's comment, please register your own application.
What you are trying to do with the ID of the powershell client won't work as far as I know, nor will incremental/dynamic consent with ADAL 3.13.  MSAL (a new auth client library) does support incremental consent, and you could try that instead, but MSAL is in preview (and you'll need to register your app at apps.dev.microsoft.com). Alternatively, if you want to keep using ADAL, you can register your app using the Azure Portal  at portal.azure.com, by searching for the app registration blade, where you'll want to register a native client app, and request permissions to users, mail and anything else you need in Microsoft Graph.

BTW - out of interest, what are you trying to do here?  Are you trying to create a PowerShell client for Outlook and Microsoft Graph?  If we offered a Microsoft Graph PowerShell client, would this interest you?  If so please request this on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Hope this helps,